# Good way for login aplication in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, file, account

I want to create a little Login application using Java in Android Studio. I have done this just with Java and have used a File on my own computer for it. That wont work with when the app is downloaded on other devices. at least that's what I think. I have used a file in the format of username:password, split it on ":" and then transferred it into a hash map. Can I have a "central" File where every new account gets added to? Or is there an other better way to do that? I have no clue on how to do that and can't find a solution on YouTube or google. I want to add: I don't want to have the best or most effective solution for it but the easiest. I am completely new to Android and kind of new to Java and programming in general. I just want something to write accounts to and read them out.

Comment: your question is not clear, Please provide a proper explanation in fewer words with some piece of code.

Comment: Code is not needed for my question since it's not about an error or something similar. Can you provide me what is unclear about my question?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should read about sqllite. It`s a database made for android studio. Basically you save the username and the password into a file for each user and when you try to login, you will read all the username-password combinations to see if one matches. If one matches ,it's a login.

Comment: I've heard about SQLite, but it's local, isn't it? so you cant login to an account created on another device. And even two accounts with the same username could exist as long as they are on different devices

Comment: Yes, it is local. You can check all usernames before adding one so there won't be duplicates. If you want a cloud connection, use firebase. It's well made and easy to use.

Comment: @AnsG As noted, SQLite is a local-only database. At least on its own. You could of course also write your own server that manages accounts across devices, where that server uses SQLite behind the scenes (though I would recommend a different RDBMS in that case). But as you're on Android, consider using [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/). It can be used across devices (i.e., non-local). It also has authentication services built-in (along with many other things, such as cloud storage).

Answer (score 0):

I Agree with **Cosmin** but we have also some best practices for this Like you can use the room database instead of Sqlite. Also, you can use SharedPreferences for storing the Current User.

room reference : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-perform-crud-operations-in-room-database-in-android/

shared preferences reference : https://www.tutlane.com/tutorial/android/android-shared-preferences-with-examples